# How to put a part of result in R markdown

Tags: r, r-markdown

I get this result on console when I run step() function

like :

```
s2 = step(m2)

## Start:  AIC=-19124.39
## z ~ a_speed + b_speed + separation + s_separation + rate_terms + 
##     mpa + load_time + highpressure_time
## 
##                     Df Sum of Sq    RSS    AIC
## - s_separation       1    0.0000 176.35 -19126
## - separation         1    0.0237 176.37 -19126
## <none>                           176.35 -19124
## - highpressure_time  1    0.1141 176.47 -19123
## - a_speed            1    0.2016 176.55 -19120
## - rate_terms         1    0.3180 176.67 -19116
## - load_time          1    0.7352 177.09 -19103
## - b_speed            1    0.9715 177.32 -19096
## - mpa                1   20.0644 196.41 -18528
## 
## Step:  AIC=-19126.39
## z ~ a_speed + b_speed + separation + rate_terms + mpa + load_time + 
##     highpressure_time
## 
##                     Df Sum of Sq    RSS    AIC
## - separation         1    0.0238 176.37 -19128
## <none>                           176.35 -19126
## - highpressure_time  1    0.1347 176.49 -19124
## - a_speed            1    0.2120 176.56 -19122
## - rate_terms         1    0.3238 176.67 -19118
## - load_time          1    0.7356 177.09 -19105
## - b_speed            1    1.0988 177.45 -19094
## - mpa                1   20.4260 196.78 -18520
## 
## Step:  AIC=-19127.64
## z ~ a_speed + b_speed + rate_terms + mpa + load_time + highpressure_time
## 
##                     Df Sum of Sq    RSS    AIC
## <none>                           176.37 -19128
## - highpressure_time  1    0.1497 176.52 -19125
## - rate_terms         1    0.3827 176.76 -19118
## - a_speed            1    0.4609 176.84 -19115
## - load_time          1    0.7879 177.16 -19105
## - b_speed            1    1.0960 177.47 -19095
## - mpa                1   26.2195 202.59 -18360
```

But I want to show just last result of steps on R markdown

this part :

```
## Step:  AIC=-19127.64
## z ~ a_speed + b_speed + rate_terms + mpa + load_time + highpressure_time
## 
##                     Df Sum of Sq    RSS    AIC
## <none>                           176.37 -19128
## - highpressure_time  1    0.1497 176.52 -19125
## - rate_terms         1    0.3827 176.76 -19118
## - a_speed            1    0.4609 176.84 -19115
## - load_time          1    0.7879 177.16 -19105
## - b_speed            1    1.0960 177.47 -19095
## - mpa                1   26.2195 202.59 -18360
```

Is it possible to show only part of result..???

I googled this, but no luck. Any suggestion for this problem or keywords for searching this

Please give any suggestions..!

Comment: please add info on the packages you are using and, if possible, provide a reprex. It will dramatically improve your chances of getting a good and quick answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could probably use `capture.output` to capture the output of your model, and then output only the lines you need.
As an example on a linear model :

```
m <- lm(cyl~mpg,data= mtcars)     
output <- capture.output(summary(m))

output[1:11]
 [1] ""                                                    
 [2] "Call:"                                               
 [3] "lm(formula = cyl ~ mpg, data = mtcars)"              
 [4] ""                                                    
 [5] "Residuals:"                                          
 [6] "    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max "            
 [7] "-1.8569 -0.6484  0.1205  0.5965  1.5876 "            
 [8] ""                                                    
 [9] "Coefficients:"                                       
[10] "            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    "
[11] "(Intercept) 11.26068    0.59304   18.99  < 2e-16 ***"
```

Then in `RMarkdown`:

````
```{r,results='asis'}
m <- lm(cyl~mpg,data= mtcars)     
output <- capture.output(summary(m))
invisible(lapply(output[1:11],function(txt) cat(txt,'\n')))
```
````

[image]
You can use `echo=F` to hide the code part.

Answer (score 1):

The output is hard-coded in the `stats::step` function. If you type the function name at the R console, you can see the source code:

```r
step
#Skipping 86 lines
  if (trace) {
    cat("Start:  AIC=", format(round(bAIC, 2)), "\n", cut.string(deparse(formula(fit))), 
        "\n\n", sep = "")
    flush.console()
  }
#41 more lines
      if (trace) 
        print(aod[o, ])
#More lines
```

You will see that the output is printed at every iteration.

One possible way to change this behavior is to make a copy and modify the output:

```
mystep <- step
fix(mystep)
```

The `fix` function allows you to edit a function. By making two simple changes and calling the function with `trace = FALSE` you can get your desired output:
[image]

```
summary(lm1 <- lm(Fertility ~ ., data = swiss))
mystep(lm1,trace = 0)

Step:  AIC=189.86
Fertility ~ Agriculture + Education + Catholic + Infant.Mortality

                   Df Sum of Sq    RSS    AIC
- Examination       1     53.03 2158.1 189.86
<none>                          2105.0 190.69
- Agriculture       1    307.72 2412.8 195.10
- Infant.Mortality  1    408.75 2513.8 197.03
- Catholic          1    447.71 2552.8 197.75
- Education         1   1162.56 3267.6 209.36

Call:
lm(formula = Fertility ~ Agriculture + Education + Catholic + 
    Infant.Mortality, data = swiss)

Coefficients:
     (Intercept)       Agriculture         Education          Catholic  Infant.Mortality  
         62.1013           -0.1546           -0.9803            0.1247            1.0784
```